# Screen freezing or 2 finger scrolling don't work

Tags: 14.04, kernel, touchpad, multi-touch, focaltech

I have problem with my Ubuntu kernel and I don't know what to do.

1. All my upgraded kernel from this moment: 3.18.0, 3.18.3, 3.19.0-23, 3.19.0-25 have randomly moment with it make my pc freezing or after I put it on hibernate or just if I working on it.
2. If I've use first kernel I've 3.13(it has come with my Ubuntu 14.04) it works and don't make my screen freezing but with it I can't use scrolling with 2 finger on touchpad

Here it's all my kernel version:
[image]
and here it's my `xinput`:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse                 id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam                     id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

And don't say to go in Settings and activated 2 finger scrolling because I don't have it.
[image]

So, know anyone how can I make my 2 finger scrolling works in kernel 3.13 or how I can make my rest of kernel works fine with out freezing?

Output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'; dmesg | grep pnp`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 178d
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 139a (rev a2)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 178d
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia

[    0.260093] pnp 00:0a: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs FLT0102 SYN0a00 SYN0002 PNP0f03 PNP0f13 PNP0f12 (active)
```

And my laptop mode is Asus F550J.
[That is my laptop.](http://www.emag.ro/laptop-asus-cu-procesor-intelr-coretm-i7-4720hq-2-60ghz-haswelltm-15-6-full-hd-8gb-1tb-nvidia-geforce-gtx-950m-4gb-free-dos-black-silver-f550jx-dm020d/pd/DPPVRMBBM/)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'; dmesg | grep pnp` terminal command. And also please specify  the laptop model.

Answer (score 0):

You have a new Nvidia adapter and a Focaltech touchpad.

It seems that you have installed the Focaltech driver, because your touchpad worked in multitouch mode with kernel 3.19.

You can fix all issues by installing a new Nvidia proprietary driver. Just in case I will give commands to install the Focaltech driver too.

Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```

and reboot.

Then run

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/focaltech-dkms
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime focaltech-dkms
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

and reboot again.

You can also switch to the Intel adapter by running

```
sudo prime-select intel
```

Comment: I need do that in kernel 3.13 or 3.19? because touchpad works fine in 3.19 where I've freezing problem

Comment: Just in 3.13 it don't works

Comment: This will install kernel 3.19. And it should boot there by default, if you did not install any higher numbered kernels. Focaltech will never work on 3.13. And it works in 3.19, because you installed the driver.

Comment: Nop... that don't solve my problem, again he block again and he show me that error message(that not new error, it's the same error at the last block after I've install what do you told me) http://i.imgur.com/mBKhwdg.png

Comment: It looks like this is related to suspend. And what is your wireless adapter? Did you do `sudo apt-get upgrade`?

Comment: what is with my wireless adapter? and yes, I do sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: Yes, the wireless adapter. I see that wl driver is installed. `lspci -nn | grep Net`

Comment: there is the output `03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
`

Comment: That is a correct driver. Try to do `sudo prime-select intel`, log off and log on.

Comment: K, I did that, now I will waiting to see if my error persisting or that solve it :)

Comment: And again no... I've obtain that error again:  http://i.imgur.com/lAgHxiq.png

Comment: My PC has block again x2 time in 10min :(, but I think I've found something. I'm not sure but I think that can cause the freezing. When I've started Ubuntu, before to started loaded Ubuntu he show me that message: `Error  parsing PCC subspaces from PCCT` and on the next line `ACPI PCC probe failed`